# Fortran array of pointer arrays defined as pointer (bug in ifort 11.1?)

Tags: arrays, pointers, fortran, fortran90, intel-fortran

I have one question and one problem (I think they are related).

Question: Can I use in Fortran 90 array of pointer arrays defined as pointer?

```
type string
  character, pointer :: str(:)
end type

type(string), pointer :: arr(:)
```

Problem:
I have code (see below) for which ifort 11.1 gives segfault in the last write. Other compilers, such as gfortran 4.6.3, ifort 11.1.072, 12.0.1, ..., worked without a problem

You can think about the code as simulation of Python append function.

```
program test
implicit none

type string
  integer,   pointer :: key
  character, pointer :: str(:)
end type

type(string), pointer :: arr(:), tmp(:)

allocate(arr(1))
allocate(arr(1)%str(1))
arr(1)%str(1) = 'A'
write(6,*) arr(1)%str(1)

! --------------------

tmp => arr
write(6,*) tmp(1)%str(1)

! --------------------

nullify(arr)
allocate(arr(2))
arr(1)%str => tmp(1)%str
write(6,*) arr(1)%str(1)

end program
```

Expected result is:

```
A
A
A
```

ifort 11.1 gives segmentation fault on the last line. Now comes the weird thing. If you comment out declaration of integer in type string you will get the expected result also with ifort 11.1.

Is this compiler problem or am I using non-standard Fortran 90 structures?

Comment: It could be a compiler bug if it works with `11.1.072` but not with an earlier build of `11.1`.

Comment: It also worked with 11.0. But usually I have more trust in guys from compiler business than in my own abilities :).

Comment: I always report suspected compiler problems to Intel tech support (well, always when it's an Intel compiler that is). I find them even better than SO at identifying bugs in their products. Of course in this case they may well respond 'yes, that was a bug in that version of the compiler, now fixed'.

Comment: Always use tag [tag:fortran] and only add the version when necessary to distinguish that your question is specific. For example that you cannot use Fortran 2008 but only Fortran 90.

Answer (score 2):

Your code compiles and executes without a problem using Intel Fortran 13.0.something. Together with your experience with other compilers and compiler versions this does suggest a compiler bug, albeit one that is now corrected.

I'm not entirely sure what the Python append function does, but if you are looking for a Fortran way to make strings whose contents (and lengths) can change dynamically you should seriously consider using the Fortran 2003 automatic allocation features.  For example, you could define a string like this:

```
character(len=:), allocatable :: string1
```

give it a value like this:

```
string1 = 'this is string 1'
```

and give it another value like this:

```
string1 = 'this is'
```

or like this

```
string1 = string1//' more text'
```

Observe the complete lack of statements allocating the size of `string1` or reallocating it.

Comment: Yes, I was already thinking about it. I should definitely give it a try.